# Jenkins Templates and inheritance

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I have 10 types of jobs, that I want to turn into templates. These for example all share the same SCM repository configuration.

Do I have to copy the SCM settings into every template or is there some other way to do it? Inheritance and supertypes looked interesting, but do not seem to do it or I haven't figured out how to use is correctly. Auxiliary models maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think at the moment you need to copy the SCM settings into each template. There is a plan to create a template kind for SCMs, which would make this easier as you could define an SCM template once and then “call” it from each job template—or for that matter from a non-templatized job.

Auxiliary models and inheritance are not designed to make the templates themselves (i.e. their transformers) simpler; they exist to make it possible to supply complex configuration UIs for template attributes, where a simple object model is the most natural way of representing configuration (rather than, say, parsing a DSL).